# Como eu deixaria essa minha expressão para além do caracter - (menos) ser aceito o + (mais) também?

Tags: html, regex

Eu tenho uma expressão em um `input`, utilizando `pattern`, que tem algumas regras, entre elas: Aceitar letras maiúsculas, minúsculas, mínimo de 5 caracteres, não aceitar caracteres especiais (somente aceitar o -).

```
pattern="^[A-Za-zÀ-ú0-9., -]{5,}"
```

Eu gostaria de fazê-lo aceitar também o caractere `+` (mais).

**Segue abaixo meu `input`:**

```html
<label for="razao-social-novo">Razão Social:</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Não são permitidos caracteres especiais" pattern="^[A-Za-zÀ-ú0-9., -]{5,}" required />
```

Comment: Só um adendo aqui. Foram-me indicados dois sites ótimos para realização de testes nas nossas regex criadas: https://regexr.com/ (esse eu entrei e é muito bom mesmo). https://regex101.com/ (esse falaram que é muito bom também).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta adicionar o `+` dentro dos colchetes:

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Não são permitidos caracteres especiais"
 pattern="^[+A-Za-zÀ-ú0-9., -]{5,}" required />
            ^ aqui
```

Outro detalhe, da forma que está, ainda aceita caracteres inválidos, pois a regex só verifica se a string começa com 5 ou mais desses caracteres (mas pode ter qualquer outra coisa depois).

Então eu sugiro adicionar também o [marcador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `$`, que indica o fim da string. Assim você garante que ela só pode ter o que está especificado na regex:

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Não são permitidos caracteres especiais"
 pattern="^[+A-Za-zÀ-ú0-9., -]{5,}$" required />
                                  ^ aqui
```

Comment: Funcionou certinho. Só uma última coisa, antes eu havia tentado assim: pattern="^[A-Za-zÀ-ú0-9.+, -]{5,}" e também havia funcionado. Minha dúvida é, qual a diferença em relação ao posicionamento do caracter + na sua resposta e nesse pattern aqui que eu coloquei ?

Comment: @Gambi Nenhuma, não deveria fazer diferença. Só coloquei no começo pra ficar mais fácil de ver. O único que não pode ficar em qualquer lugar é o `-` senão ele é interpretado como intervalo (no caso de `a-z`, por exemplo), mas os outros caracteres, tanto faz a ordem em que aparecem

Comment: Sim, e se eu colocar ali o +- juntos, dá problema também. Pois, não sei pq, é interpretado o +- como um único caracter. Tipo: pattern="^[A-Za-zÀ-ú0-9., +-]{5,}" , isso daria errado.

Comment: @Gambi Ué, testei aqui e deu certo. Ah, estou testando com o `$` no final também. Mas enfim, aqui não deu errado...

Comment: Muito obrigado!